# How to completely disable entry versioning(drafts) during editing

Tags: craft3, craft4, craft-features, entry-versions

[image]

Obviously I disabled it in the section settings:

[image]

I just want to save the entry after making all the changes, but now it's trying to save the revision after each single change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing are provisional drafts, they aren't published until you hit enter. This is good to have so you don't lose your work if you accidentally close the browser tab or your computer crashes unexpectedly.

You can disable automatic drafts completely by setting the [general config setting `autosaveDrafts`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#autosavedrafts) to `false`.

Comment: exactly what I need. I used `CRAFT_AUTOSAVE_DRAFTS=false` in .`.env` file. Thanks!